# Telerik UI For UWP DataGrid Enter Key

Tags: uwp, telerik-grid

I am using the Telerik Datagrid For UWP. I am using  the `PreviewKeyDown` to capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I want to set focus to another control when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

```
private async void bookingGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key==Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
        //the methodfires but focus does not shift to the required control
        await FocusManager.TryFocusAsync(anotherControl, FocusState.Keyboard);
        // this does not focus the other control??
     }
}
```

Other keys work fine but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key does not. I've tried

```
    e.Handled = true;
```

And

```
    e.Handled = false;
```

Comment: Could you try `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` event instead of `PreviewKeyDown`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the fact that you are setting the `e.Handled = true` too late.

When the `await` is reached, the execution of the event handler basically stops for the system, so if you set `Handled` after the `await`, it will not be picked up by the system and it will continue executing `KeyDown` which will very likely prevent the focus to be set to another control and keep it in the `DataGrid`.

What you will need is to set `Handled` before focus is changed:

```
private async void bookingGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key==Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
        e.Handled = true;
        await FocusManager.TryFocusAsync(anotherControl, FocusState.Keyboard);
     }
}
```

Alternative solution would be to et the control process the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press and set the focus in the `KeyUp` event handler for example.